# Products don't showed in manage products

Tags: magento-1.9, magento-1

I have a problem with this code:

```
$website = Mage::app()->getWebsite($website->getId());
            $store_id = $website->getDefaultStore()->getId();
            $_grouped_products = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->getCollection()
            ->addAttributeToFilter('type_id', Mage_Catalog_Model_Product_Type::TYPE_GROUPED)
            ->addStoreFilter($store_id)
            ->addWebsiteFilter($website->getId())
            ->setStore($storeId);
```

The function ->getCollection() return a product with the SKU "EHSXB16P50A / ERLQ014CW1" and in the backend of magento:

[image: No results found]

I go to database to search this product and exist:
[image: mysql found product]

Any idea?

Comment: Can you click on reset filter? and search again may be your search keyword contains blank space.

Comment: Yes, I reset the filter and clean cache and nothing happened